# Definitive guidelines for web developer and access to virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, phpstorm, development-environment

I spent hours testing and researching, still I haven't got what i'm looking for. 
I develop web applications (php, mysql and so on). We work in team so every developer should have his own VM where to run and test apps, and then commit changes to LAN repository.
When I am in the office I have my own VM running Debian, on VirtualBox or VMWare (tried both) bridged mode. VM has got static IP address, so i access through the browser with http://192.168.1.80/appname.
I use phpStorm (or Eclipse) as php editor. I work with local project and remote server (local project in my computer and remote server is the vm). When the code changes, remote server is synchronized as well. To do that i was asked a network map, so i map 192.168.1.80 -> S:. Now my remote webroot is on S:
Everything works fine.

The problems start when i'm not at office. Bridged mode, NAT mode, nothing works. I cannot access anymore to VM's static ip address. After lots of researches I figured out I have to use 'host-only' mode. Ok. Done. 
The problem is host only network runs an internal DHCP or sort of. So I had to change Debian network configuration (waste of time tomorrow in the office to switch back again..) to use DHCP.
Ok now my computer is using vmware's 192.168.174.* and so is vm. I can access through the browser.
But now my S: is pointing to 192.168.1.80 static address and phpStorm is not working any more..

Let's get to the point: after spending hours and hours in tests, the question is: "How does the modern good PHP developer to set up a clean environment to be used wherever and whatever network he is attached (or not attached) to?"

Thank you

Comment: On which operating system? Did you consider installing natively Linux on your laptop or home machine?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro. No, I cannot switch SO due to other company requirements and software compatibility

Comment: where is VM ? local or remote ?

Comment: Vm is local, on my PC

Comment: Maybe I found a solution: mapping network folder, desktop link and so on using debian hostname, rather than IP. Still here for futher suggests, thank you.